# How can I get the term ID out of the hierarchical select theming function?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I'm attempting to add a link to flag each term output by hierarchical select in a views template.

Here's the relevant code from hs_taxonomy.module:

```
function theme_hs_taxonomy_formatter_lineage($variables) {
  $output = '';
  $lineage = $variables['lineage'];
  $separator = theme('hierarchical_select_item_separator');
  dpm($variables);

  // Render each item within a lineage.
  $items = array();
  foreach ($lineage as $level => $item ) {
    dpm($lineage);
    $line  = '<span class="lineage-item lineage-item-level-' . $level . '">';
    $line .= drupal_render($item);
    $line .= '</span>';
    dpm($item);
    $items[] = $line;
  }
  $output .= implode($separator, $items);

  return $output;
}
```

And here's the output of `dpm($item)`:
[image: debug output]

[Based on the flag module documentation](http://drupal.org/node/295383), I tried to add the link like this: `$line .= flag_create_link('hobbies', $term->$item['#options']['entity']['tid']);`

But that gives this error:
**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /mysite/sites/all/modules/contrib/hierarchical_select/modules/hs_taxonomy.module on line 880**

How can I get the tid of the term being output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity is a `stdClass` [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), you need to use the `->` accessor:

```
flag_create_link('hobbies', $term->$item['#options']['entity']->tid);
```